# How to return values inside a SQL table?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I have this Discord.py economy project, how can I select exp inside this SQL table and return it to the user inside an embed?

[image: sql]

Code:

```
@commands.command()
async def balance(self, ctx):
    db = sqlite3.connect('banco.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_id, exp, lvl FROM levels WHERE guild_id = {ctx.author.guild.id} AND user_id = {ctx.author.id}')
    result1 = cursor.fetchone()
    exp = int(result1[1])
        
    for i in range(1,99):
        if exp == i :
            em = discord.Embed(title = f'{ctx.author.name}', color = (0xbbbbbb))
            em.add_field(name = 'LOJINHA 2.0 ',value = int(result1[3]) )
            em.add_field(name = 'LOJINHA 2.0',value = 'C')
            em.set_author(name='LOJINHA 2.0', icon_url='https://i.imgur.com/X4u3yOW.png') 
            em.set_thumbnail(url='https://i.imgur.com/f05uKPn.png')  
            await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

I might need some help with this line of code:

```
         em.add_field(name = 'LOJINHA 2.0 ',value = int(result1[3])
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 855, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
>
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: tuple index out of range
>
> ^CMarcoss-Air:economia CIP$
> Marcoss-Air:economia CIP$

Comment: Can you print ``result1`` and say what that returns? As you're getting an IndexError, it doesn't contain what you'd expect it to

Comment: result1 = ('129329540429381632', '53', '0')

Comment: Uhhhh i got it now result1[2]